# Does refugee status sometimes have civic benefits over normal citizenship?

Tags: refugee-law

Just hypothetically, if someone felt they could qualify for refugee status but that there may be other feasible ways for them to try to move to another country as well, would there be any reason for them to choose to pursue refugee status merely because of additional benefits like social services, better terms on their period of stay, etc.? Do refugees have any perks above that of non-refugee citizens?

Comment: Refugee status does not confirm citizenship. It grants someone legal authorization to living in a country based upon a refugee status visa. This question seems to be confused about that point.

Comment: I don't read any part of this question that implies the OP thinks refugee status might "confirm citizenship".  But, the answer depends entirely on the country in question.

Answer (score 0):

> because of additional benefits like social services, better terms on their period of stay, etc.? Do refugees have any perks above that of non-refugee citizens?

The main advantage of refugee status is that the authorities of the country of refuge are not allowed to send the refugee back to the country of citizenship because the refugee fears persecution there.  For example, suppose a highly skilled scientist from country X fears for her life because the new government of country X is persecuting people of her ethnicity.  She can try the normal route: make applications to various countries under their highly skilled migrant programs, or scientific exchange programs, or she can look for a company that can sponsor her for a work visa.  This can take weeks or months, during which time she is vulnerable to persecution.  Alternatively, she can leave the country immediately and seek asylum.  Legally speaking, end becomes a refugee the moment she crosses the border; an application for refugee status is really just an application for a country's authorities to recognize and acknowledge the facts.  If your life were in danger, which would you choose?

As to the status in the country of refuge, whether this is more or less favorable for refugees or people in some other status depends on the country's immigration law and on the particular other status.  For example, what happens if you lose your job?  If you have come on a temporary work visa, you might lose the visa.  At that point you'd have to apply for asylum anyway.

Some countries have asylum support programs where they help you with housing and maybe a small stipend for a few months.  This support generally ends once you have a job, which would typically be pretty quick for someone who could have qualified for a work visa.

Basically, the refugee system is designed for people who need to leave home suddenly, and work visa programs are not.  For most people it will make the most sense to use the route that is designed for their circumstances.